# Include multiple directories in RCFLAGS

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am using **nmake** to compile a makefile.msc file

I have to include the below directories

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt
```

in the /I atrribute of the RCFLAGS

What I have tried are below :

1st try:

```
RCFLAGS  = /I "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" /I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt"
```

2nd try:

```
RCPATH  = "'c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um':'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared':'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt'"

RCFLAGS = /I $(RCPATH)
```

Everytime, RC complaints about different missing headers.

Please give a guideline on how to achieve what I am trying to do.
Many thanks in advance.

Edit : Many resources elaborate how to do this with CFLAGS but are
not specific about RCFLAGS. Moreover, there is little help if I do
a `rc /?`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it by the below format :

```
-I "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" -I "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\winrt" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include"
```

Sounds silly though since the delimiter `/` is accepted for the first RCFLAGS attribute which is `/dWIN32`.